# Android addTextChangedListener does not go into submethods

Tags: android

I am studying Android now and I ran into a problem.
I used an addTextChangedListener in a fragment of my navigation drawer project. The text never changed as it should be changing according to the EditText View. I tried to debug and it shows the compiler does not go into any of the 3 submethods of the listener. Does anyone have a clue what is going on?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner fromSpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        setTitle("ezConvert");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.temperature:
                TempFragment tempFragment = new TempFragment();
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_main, tempFragment).commit();

                break;
            case R.id.length:

                break;
            case R.id.volume:

                break;
            case R.id.weight:

                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:

                break;
            case R.id.contact:

                break;
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

TempFragment.java:

```
public class TempFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private Spinner fromSpinner;
    private Spinner toSpinner;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter1;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter2;
    private View rootView;
    private EditText input;
    private TextView display;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_temp, container, false);
        input = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fromValue);
        display = rootView.findViewById(R.id.result);

        fromSpinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.convertFrom);
        adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.array.temp,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        fromSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
        fromSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        toSpinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.convertTo);
        adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.array.temp,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        toSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
        toSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void convert(){
        display.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
          //  @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

           // @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(fromSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Celsius[℃]") && toSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Fahrenheit[℉]")){
                    double inputNum = Double.valueOf(input.getText().toString());
                    double result = inputNum * 1.8 + 32;
                    display.setText(input.getText().toString() + " " + fromSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + " = " + result + " " + toSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                }
                else if(fromSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(toSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString())){
                    display.setText(input.getText().toString() + " " + fromSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + " = " + input.getText().toString() + " " + toSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                }
            }

           // @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        convert();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

fragemnt_temp.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fromTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:text="From: "
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:height="40dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/convertFrom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fromTitle" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/fromValue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fromTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="From"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fromValue"
    android:text="To: "
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:height="40dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/convertTo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fromValue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toTitle" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/convertTo"
    android:text="Result"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:height="40dp" />
```

I believe the problem is because of the debugger keep telling me "no such instance field display". It should be resolved if this problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `convert()` just set addTextChangedListener, but does not really change any text, so no callback is never triggered.
And, if you need to change TextView's text by EditText, should add the listener to EditText.
Try:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_temp, container, false);
    input = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fromValue);
    display = rootView.findViewById(R.id.result);
    fromSpinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.convertFrom);
    adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.array.temp,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    fromSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
    fromSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    toSpinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.convertTo);
    adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.array.temp,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    toSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
    toSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      //  @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

       // @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            convert();
        }

       // @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    convert();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

private void convert() {
    if(fromSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Celsius[℃]") && toSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Fahrenheit[℉]")){
                double inputNum = Double.valueOf(input.getText().toString());
                double result = inputNum * 1.8 + 32;
                display.setText(input.getText().toString() + " " + fromSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + " = " + result + " " + toSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }
            else if(fromSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(toSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString())){
                display.setText(input.getText().toString() + " " + fromSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + " = " + input.getText().toString() + " " + toSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Should've set to EditText instead of TextView